# Download mvc3 for XP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Where can I download MVC3 for Win XP?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't hard to find on Google: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a920ccee-1397-4feb-824a-2dfefee47d54&displaylang=en) is the latest RC.

Answer (score 1):

The MVC official page has a link to it, but the best way is to use the Web Platform installer (http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)